# Best Approach to fetch and insert 1 million data in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

My Question is not about code. I want to ask question regarding performance of core data.

@edited
What are approaches to insert and fetch 1 million objects in core data if single object contain simple single string property ?

This question is for my knowledge.

Comment: If its a kinda pre-populate a database kinda thing, generally only call create instead of the usual fetch/create and dont call save til the end.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Thanks ! It will be grateful if more help is available.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is a rich and sophisticated object graph management framework capable of dealing with large volumes of data. The SQLite store can scale to terabyte-sized databases with billions of rows, tables, and columns.

Unless your entities themselves have very large attributes or large numbers of properties, 1 million objects is considered as medium size for a data set.

That means, that if your objects doesn't have 100+ rows, or huge values of binary data, your workflow shouldn't be different to what you apply to set of 100 objects.